# Keyboard short cut for chrome to switch between 2 tabs at random position without using Ctrl+[1-9] or Ctrl+Shift+Tab or Ctrl+Tab

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want keyborad short cut for chrome to switch between two tabs at random postion. Like we have in Firefox Hold control key and then press tab you can jump /toggle between any two tabs.

Comment: Ctrl + tab option works well in chromium

Comment: Ctrl+Tab works well but I want to switch between/toggle between two tabs position at number 3 and number 6 directly. without using ctrl+[1-9]

Comment: Are you asking for something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-switch-recent-last/odhjcgnlbagjllfbilicalpigimhdcll?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: Or maybe https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: yes I am looking for something like e chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-switch-recent-last.... but without any add ons or extension